# Ubuntu Server won't work in QEMU: KERNEL PANIC

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I tried to install ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso in QEMU as a virtual machine.

This was my command to generate the image file:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 confImage 100G
```

After creating the image file I installed ubuntu with the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86-64 -cdrom /home/username/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso -boot order=d -drive file=confImage,format=qcow2
```

The installation went fine so I started it afterwards with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 confImage
```

But after choosing ubuntu in the GRUB-Loader I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Based on the error the assumption is that you did not reserve enough memory. You may find this helpful: http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html

Answer (score 6):

Try

`qemu-system-x86_64 -hda confImage -m 1024`

Comment: It works, but why does it work?

Comment: @C-- My guess, as someone who experienced this, is that you get a kernel panic if the VM doesn't satisfy the minimum requirement for installed RAM. I was getting this behaviour in aqemu with its Linux 2.6 x86-64 template'd default of 256MiB and, when I noticed and bumped it up to a 4GiB more reasonable for the Lubuntu ISO I had "inserted", it allowed a successful boot.